# Xcode preprocessor dependent on environment variable

Tags: xcode, preprocessor, environment-variables, xcodebuild

I have a configuration that I'd like to dynamically control a preprocessor defined value through an environment variable.

Is this possible? if it is how do I set in the preprocessor define table that I want to set the value based on the environment variable?

Answer (score 3):

In the "Build Settings" of a target of your project, you can add something like that to the "Preprocessor Macros" field:

```
DEV_USERNAME="${USER}"
```

Of course, the `USER` variable can be replaced by any environment variable available to Xcode build system. To get a list of those, you can add a run script to your target and enable the checkmark "Show environment variables in build log."

You can then use the `DEV_USERNAME` preprocessor macro in your code. And if you want to use it as a string, you can "stringify" it:

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s

xstr(DEV_USERNAME)
```

This will give you the username surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: I came across something which you may find interesting (or not), take a loot at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30396593/734860

Comment: Interesting, indeed! But maybe not in this case.

Comment: Yes, this question is more general.