# Setting up user specific preprocessor macros for Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I'd like to be able to have specific code blocks such as `#ifdef SOME_VARIABLE` and the value of variable would be filled at project's build time if the project is being built on a specific user's machine.

Is that possible?

Comment: Could you use an Info.plist instead of #ifdef? Do you really need build differently? If so could you use different build configurations? How many different SOME_VARIABLE's would there be.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088380/xcode-preprocessor-dependent-on-environment-variable but I don't see the value of the macro in code.

Comment: But are you doing a conditional compile or just need the value in your code. I set the version number minor and major and git hash in my Info.plist with a build script then read the Info.plist in my code to get the values and display them. See my answer second to last in post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730186/how-do-i-force-xcode-to-rebuild-the-info-plist-file-in-my-project-every-time-i-b/16332406#16332406

Comment: I want to conditionally compile some code based on a specific username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the value in the "Preprocessor Macros" Build Settings. Setting "SOME_VARIABLE=${USER}" in the build settings is equivalent to #define SOME_VARIABLE   "jappleseed" in your code.

Then in your code you can do this:

```
#define jappleseed 1
#define sjobs      2

#if DEV_USER == jappleseed
    NSLog(@"Hi Jhonny");
#elif DEV_USER == sjobs
    NSLog(@"Hi Steve");
#endif
```

Note: This is a contrived example if you really want the string "jappleseed" for use in your code you should be using an Info.plist and not #define

Comment: I tried that but I'm not getting the value set in the Build Settings, just the name of the define. I see the environment value expanded to the expected value in the Xcode project settings pane but when I tried to print out the define value, I see the name of the variable, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 6 (at least) you can include your username as part of the **name** of the macro in the **preprocessor macros** section of the **Build Settings**:

`ENV_USER_$(USER)=1` (this will define the macro `ENV_USER_myusername`)

Then, in your code, you can use

```
#if ENV_USER_myusername
...
#endif
```

The `=1`in the definition may be redundant, since Xcode seems to define the variable as `true` by default. We put it there just to be on the safe side and be able to use either `#if` or `#ifdef`. This way there is no concern that it might be defined, but evaluating to `false`, in which case `#ifdef` would still work but `#if`wouldn't. Of course, you might define it to be any value you wish, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 2):

in swift: add DEBUG_$(USER) to "Active Compilation Conditions"

there is no way to assign a value